# What is Spring equivalent of a Grails "plugin" (modularizing Spring applications)

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

#### Background

I have an existing [Grails](https://grails.org/) application which I'm rewriting in [Spring](http://spring.io/). My Grails application *(simplified for example)* has 2 [plugins](https://grails.github.io/grails-doc/3.0.x/guide/plugins.html#creatingAndInstallingPlugins), `UserProfilePlugin` and `UserOrderPlugin` where each plugin has its own **code + config + resources**. Depending on a client's request, I can generate an application which is compiled/packaged to include:

1. Both `UserProfilePlugin` and `UserOrderPlugin` to display both User Profiles and User Orders
2. Only `UserProfilePlugin` to display only User Profiles
3. Only `UserOrderPlugin` to display only User Orders

#### Problem

I want to modularize my Spring application to have multiple **code + config + resources** units which can be included/excluded from the main application at compile/package time and can be reused across multiple applications. But I'm struggling to find Spring's equivalent of a Grails [plugin](https://grails.github.io/grails-doc/3.0.x/guide/plugins.html#creatingAndInstallingPlugins). I have already gone through Spring's official documentation [1](https://spring.io/docs), [2](http://docs.spring.io/platform/docs/2.0.0.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/), [3](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/), [4](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/), etc. but could not find anything useful. On the contrary, Spring application (as per the document) looks more like one monolithic unit with no reusable sub-units inside it.

Am I missing something obvious? Can someone please throw some light on this?

Answer (score 0):

Spring does not have such a concept, but there are several ways to implement it.
The easiest way is probably to have a component scan in your application that would pick up all components from the optional package.

Let's say your "module" defines a top-level package "com.yourcompany.yourapp.module", then you would just have to make sure that all other parts of the same app are underneath "com.yourcompany.yourapp" and set your component scan to "com.yourcompany.yourapp".

---

If you are not a big fan of component scan, the cleanest way I can think of is the [Java `ServiceLoader` SPI](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ServiceLoader.html). You could define an interface that does the registration with Spring, e.g.

```
public interface SpringConfig{
    void register(ApplicationContext ac);
}
```

(I'm sure you can improve on this design)

Anyway, in each module, you'd have a file called
`/META-INF/services/com.yourcompany.yourapp.SpringConfig`
that lists all implementations this module holds. In your central app, you could then have a component that initializes the modules:

```
@Component
public class ModuleInitializer implements ApplicationContextAware, InitializingBean {


    private ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    @Override
    public void setApplicationContext(final ApplicationContext applicationContext) {

        this.applicationContext = applicationContext;
    }

    @Override
    public void afterPropertiesSet() throws Exception {
        for (SpringConfig springConfig : ServiceLoader.load(SpringConfig.class)) {
            springConfig.register(applicationContext);
        }

    }
}
```

---

In both versions, you enable / disable a module by adding it to / removing it from the classpath. So the easiest way to do that is to have one build artifact (e.g. Maven module) per application module

Comment: Yep, I saw that in the docs, but I'm looking to define stricter boundaries. E.g. `com.example.app` is main app + app config `com.example.app.userprofiles` is userprofiles module + module config and `com.example.app.userorders` is userorders module + module config. I'd rather like to keep them in separate repos, which can act as separate bundles at compile/run time (e.g. hold it's own static resources, xml configs, etc). How can I achieve this?

Comment: @JitinSameer a) I added a second version b) I don't quite understand your requirements. If I understand you correctly, all you need to do is to add the libs to the classpath and they will be there (if you go with the package name convention)

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I think I'm more interested in keeping the `code + config + resources` separate. E.g. I see **spring-security** being happily reused, so what is **spring-security** in official Spring terms, is it a bean, a module, a plugin, a top level project (which can stand on it's own), a osgi bundle?

Comment: @JitinSameer it's a library that builds on Spring

Comment: So if I want to create a *library* similar to **spring-security**, how can I do it, does it need special classes and methods (like *main* method in spring applications)? Can you refer me to official docs?

Comment: main methods only exist in Spring-Boot applications. But libraries that build on Spring will usually implement a custom BeanPostProcessor or BeanFactoryPostProcessor to extend the bean lifecycle, and if you support XML, you might think of adding a custom namespace and your own namespace handler